# Is there any n channel fet whose operating frequency range is 100Hz to 1MHz?

Tags: transistors

I searched for it a lot. Maybe I dont have the right sites. I am tired of searching. Can anyone help me plz?

http://www.biltek.tubitak.gov.tr/gelisim/elektronik/dosyalar/1/fet_2N3819.pdf

I got high frequencies jfet.

Comment: What was the nearest device you found that met your requirements? This might help us avoid searching a lot and get a quicker answer to you. Share your findings dude. Down-voted because of this but i'm quite prepared to cancel it if you show us your work so-far

Comment: @Andy I've put a link. But, its a high frequency one. I didn't get any which is below MHz!

Comment: What do you mean by "I didn't get any which is below MHz"? What property are you using to select your device?

Comment: @Anusha This is a good jfet. Here's a circuit described as an audio pre-amp - that should of course work down to 100Hz no problem. Note the alternative jfets mentioned... http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=http://www.rason.org/Projects/jfetamp/design4.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.rason.org/Projects/jfetamp/jfetamp.htm&h=309&w=535&sz=6&tbnid=tbxMXyYMzj0Q0M:&tbnh=75&tbnw=130&zoom=1&usg=__cEvdl7phbIi6dtPjQnz9WiXD91E=&docid=658h6PLEIwQatM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ALlNUZGmLom70QWkooCgDg&ved=0CEwQ9QEwAg&dur=515

Comment: Are there any FETs that *won't* operate over that range of frequencies???

Comment: I know you are new, but you have asked 3 questions here now and to be fair they are not of the best quality. People generally frown upon "text speak" (i.e. "plz"), simple shopping type questions, and unclear questions which show little effort on the askers part. Please have a read of the FAQ and ["how to ask a good question"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn how to avoid the downvotes and so it will be easier for us to help you with future questions.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty much any JFET will fit these specs. As Dave says, you'd be hard pressed to find one that doesn't.

If you have had a good look but can't find any, then you may be mistaking the maximum frequency specs for the operating frequency (i.e. it can only operate in a narrow range around that frequency when in reality it can operate from DC up to that frequency), or something like that.

The one you linked to will do fine, here is a SPICE simulation of a basic (not optimised) common source setup:

[image: JFET Circuit]

Simulation:

[image: JFET Circuit Simulation]

Above is the input and output amplitudes over the range of 10Hz to 50MHz. You can see it easily meets your basic requirements of 100Hz to 1MHz with the gain being totally flat in this area (the actual -3dB points are around 12Hz and 36MHz)

I advise doing some reading on basic FET circuits (biasing, topologies, specs, etc) so you can learn how to optimise the circuit for your purposes. Google will bring plenty up on the subject.